# SQL Embedded Select With SUM, slightly restricted

Tags: sql, sybase

I've got a slightly strange query which I've been banging my head against, I wonder if anyone would have any ideas. What makes it slightly more difficult is that it has to work in a restricted environment in an embedded product where I'm only able to alter the query after the join.

I've got a join between 2 tables to make the complete row, each row has a module id and a worked column which is either 0 for unworked and 1 for worked. Every row also has a quota column which refers to the module id and all rows with the same module id have the same quota value.

So for example data is

```
ID |Module | Quota | Complete
-------------------------
1  |A      | 1     | 0
2  |B      | 2     | 1
3  |A      | 1     | 0
4  |A      | 1     | 0
5  |B      | 2     | 1
6  |C      | 4     | 0
```

I want to select records where the Sum of the complete column for the module is less than the quota for that module.

Where I've got to is:

```
Select table_a.quota, table_a.module, table_b.complete
from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id
having table_a.quota > (select sum(table_b.complete) from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.id = table_b.id where table_a.module = *module*)
```

As I can only affect anything after the having clause, I don't know how to reference the module value from the original query's row in the embedded statement (*module*), any ideas?

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

First note, you want to use WHERE instead of HAVING, as far as I can tell; you don't have a GROUP BY.

- WHERE is applied after all joins are complete, but before any aggregation is complete.
- Having is applied after any aggregation.

In terms of referencing the outer query, inside the correlated sub-query, you need to use aliases...

```
SELECT
  table_a.quota,
  table_a.module,
  table_b.complete
FROM
  table_a
INNER JOIN
  table_b
    ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE
  table_a.quota
  >
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(lookup_b.complete)
    FROM
      table_a AS lookup_a
    INNER JOIN
      table_b AS lookup_b
        ON lookup_a.id = lookup_b.id
    WHERE
      lookup_a.module = table_a.module
  )
```

Comment: where or having both work, one of the strange quirks of Sybase.  This is pretty much what I'd been trying but I should have said that the table is given an alias in the hidden bit of the query which I can't change or see and I don't know what that alias is

Comment: You just need to ensure that the two references to the same table, and in the same scope, have different aliases.  You don't need to change the name, just give an alias, so that when referring to either table there is no ambiguity.